# Is Pakistan Army able to influence the judiciary in Pakistan?

Tags: judiciary, pakistan

Is Pakistan's army able to influence the judiciary in Pakistan so that they can control state and civil affairs?

If yes, can you give me any good examples of that with proper references and citations?

Comment: That's not usually how an army exercises (some) control. It's the implied threat of coup, which is usually realized sometimes, as I'm sure you know [given Pakistan's history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_coups_in_Pakistan) of those.

Comment: @Fizz, You are trying to generalize the question. Plz, don't do that. *That's not usually how an army exercises (some) control.* --- then you don't have any idea. *It's the implied threat of coup, which is usually realized sometimes* --- Judiciary doesn't care about coup. Coz, it is not their area of concern. E.g., Turkey has a long history of judiciary-military cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently nowadays that's somewhat indirectly exercised through the media, at least in some cases, [e.g.](https://www.mei.edu/publications/pakistans-gen-bajwa-gets-extension-amid-political-drama) when Bajwa's tenure as army chief was extended in 2019 and the Supreme Court examined the legality of that:

> The government could not even clarify whether it was an “extension” or a “re-appointment.” When the Supreme Court raised pointed questions about the constitutionality of the move, the Khan government stated that the general’s term was being extended according to Army Regulation 255. The Supreme Court rejected this argument, noting that the stated regulation does not apply to the Army chief, and forced the government to concede that Bajwa’s reappointment by the Pakistani president was in accordance with Article 243 of the Constitution. The Supreme Court therefore granted Bajwa a conditional extension for six months, asking the Khan government to have parliament pass appropriate legislation to avoid legal ambiguities in future. To add insult to injury, **the Supreme Court [observed](https://www.dawn.com/news/1519326) that it was “labeled as agents of India and the US Central Intelligence Agency (CIA) when we examined the Army Act yesterday.”**

This may indeed have been a case of not-so-successful pressure on the judges, because in the aftermath it was the legislature which put Bajwa's extra mandate on firmer grounds, as Wikipedia [notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qamar_Javed_Bajwa#Military_career):

> On 8 January 2020, the Senate of Pakistan passed the Pakistan Army (Amendment) Bill 2020, allowing for Bajwa's tenure extension up to three years until 29 November 2022.

As I suggested in my comments, in general, an army exercises the implied threat of a [military] coup, followed by military rule, which Pakistan has certainly [seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_coups_in_Pakistan) quite some stretches. And military rule can well suspend the constitution (Zia apparently did that), dismiss any judges it wants, or do worse to them.
Them being castigated as foreign agents by "voices of the people" beforehand, probably makes it easier to justify at least something like suspend/arrest them for an investigation if/when the army takes over.

And if you want an example of direct subversion like that, Musharraf did that in 2007 [when he](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musharraf_high_treason_case)

> suspended the Constitution of Pakistan, sacking fifteen Supreme Court judges and fifty-six judges of the provincial High Courts while putting the then Chief Justice of Pakistan under house arrest

Of course, that actually came to bite him back in the form of a high treason case after he was no longer head honcho.

Comment: The source is not neutral/impartial. The author is an Indian is not the issue here. The issue is, he is based in India. Apart from authors from IIT, IISc and some prominent universities like Jawaharlal University in New Delhi, I personally have no faith in these types of authors. Coz, their writings do not go through any peer review process.

Comment: @user366312 it cites a [Pakistani newspaper for the quote](https://www.dawn.com/news/1519326) from the Supreme Court. Which contains it (attributed to the chief thereof in the latter).

Comment: The latter newspaper however is much worse at summarizing the context of that led to that, like in one para.